# server.register() function throwing "register is missing", even though i have properly registered the plugins for graphql

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server, hapi

I have created a node js project with graph ql (with a very basic schema) but when i am trying to start the server after registering the plugins for graphql and graphiql, i am getting the register is missing error. Below is my code

```
const hapi=require('hapi');
const { graphqlHapi, graphiqlHapi } = require('apollo-server-hapi');
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools');

const graphqlSchema = require('./graphql/schema');
const createResolvers = require('./graphql/resolvers');

const executableSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: [graphqlSchema],
    resolvers: createResolvers(),
});

const server=hapi.server({
    port: 4000,
    host:'localhost'
});

server.register({
    plugin: graphqlHapi,
    options: {
      path: '/graphql',
      graphqlOptions: () => ({
        pretty: true,
        schema: executableSchema,
      }),
    },
});  

server.register({

    plugin: graphiqlHapi,
    options: {
      path: '/graphiql',
      graphiqlOptions: {
        endpointURL: '/graphql',
      },
    },
});

const init= async()=>{
    routes(server);
    await server.start();
    console.log(`Server is running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
}
init();
```

I had initially given the key name as register instead of plugin in the server.register() functions. In either case, i am getting the below error

> (node:19104) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is
>   deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new
>   parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
>
> (node:19104) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: AssertionError
>   [ERR_ASSERTION]: I nvalid plugin options {
>
> "plugin": {
>       "options": {
>         "path": "/graphql",
>         "graphqlOptions": () => ({\r\n        pretty: true,\r\n        schema: exe cutableSchema,\r\n      })
>       },
>       "register" [1]: -- missing --   } }

Please help me out in understanding whenter code herey this happening and how it can be rectified.

Below is the dependencies in my project

> apollo-server-hapi": "^2.3.1", "graphql": "^14.0.2", "graphql-tools":
>   "^4.0.3", "hapi": "^17.8.1",

**EDIT**
*Code after making the suggested changes*

```
const hapi=require('hapi');
const { graphqlHapi, graphiqlHapi } = require('apollo-server-hapi');
const { makeExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools');
const graphqlSchema = require('./graphql/schema');
const createResolvers = require('./graphql/resolvers');
const executableSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: [graphqlSchema],
    resolvers: createResolvers(),
  });
async function start_server() {

    const server=hapi.server({
        port: 4000,
        host:'localhost'
    });

    await server.register({
        plugin: graphqlHapi,
        options: {
        path: '/graphql',
        graphqlOptions: () => ({
            pretty: true,
            schema: executableSchema,
        }),
        route: {
            cors: true,
        },
        },

    });

    await server.register({

        plugin: graphiqlHapi,
        options: {
        path: '/graphiql',
        graphiqlOptions: {
            endpointURL: '/graphql',
        },
        route: {
            cors: true,
        },
        },

    });

    try {    
        await server.start();
        console.log(`Server is running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Error while starting server: ${err.message}`)
    }
}


start_server();
```

Comment: You should probably await each `register` call before calling `server.start`, but that may not be relevant to the error you're seeing. There's an open issue for this error on Github: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/758

Comment: @DanielRearden, i have added await and did the change as mentioned in the github issue by changing register to plugin. Please find the edited code in the original question under the header EDIT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to register the plugins in the latest release of apollo-server-hapi. It contains GraphQL playground instead of graphiql.

The below changes need to be done instead of registering.

```
const {ApolloServer} = require('apollo-server-hapi');
const executableSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
    typeDefs: [graphqlSchema],
    resolvers: createResolvers(),
  });


const server = new ApolloServer({
    schema:executableSchema
  });

async function start_server() {

    const app=hapi.server({
        port: 4000,
        host:'localhost'
    });
    await server.applyMiddleware({ app });
    try {    
        await app.start();
        console.log(`Server is running at: ${app.info.uri}`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Error while starting server: ${err.message}`)
    }
}


start_server();
```

Comment: Not working for me. What URL would it be running on?

Comment: @ClementHoang graphql playground will be available in the URL http://localhost:4000/graphql